# Ipod classic 6th gen 120gb, Harddrive Diagnostic Interpretation

Tags: hard-drive, ipod, ipod-classic, apple-diagnostics

An iPod Classic shows this but it works fine, so I don't know if it's going to fail at some point in the future?

[image]

Is a good option to buy it?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Yes i want to know if my ipod is going to fail on a near future?

Comment: Anything mechanical is likely to fail in the future - just depends on time. Basic law is if it moves then it will eventually stop - entropy...

Comment: You want to know if a *man-made, mechanical* device is going to fail sometime in the future?  The answer is “yes” because all things will at some point fail.  There’s no calculation that will take the info you provided and put an estimated failure date on your device.